# SSIS Package FTP Task Error: Directory is not specified in the file connection manager "User::ProcessingFileLocation"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have one SSIS package that has FTP task which takes files from FTP and save on my local drive but i'm getting this error:

`[FTP Task] Error: Directory is not specified in the file connection manager "User::ProcessingFileLocation"`

In FTP Editor setting :

`User::ProcessingFileLocation` used SSIS variable

Values sets to this is  `\\MYSERVER\\Raw Data\\`

Why getting this error any solution 
When i mention direct path it is working fine but having error with variable :(

Comment: How are you running the package? From BIDS/SSDT or through a SQL Agent

Comment: Did you specify the variable as an expression?

Comment: i'm running package through SQL Agent 
Variable does not have expression direct path \\MYSERVER\\Raw Data\\

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution to this problem might be the one that affected me.

The FTP task does not create the path specified in the `LocalVariable`, make sure to manually create the destination folders.

Answer (score 0):

override the UNC path with local path in Integration Services Catalog, connection manager.  Right click on the project and choose configure